# Ajax & ASP Classic Notification Display

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, notifications

I'm doing some updates for an intranet i created few years ago using ASP Classic. What i've been ask to do is to ALERT all users when news on intranet is added. Basically i need to check on database when news is added and than trigger an action to all intranet users saying you have **New Message**

I'have done a lot of research on this and i could't really find a good example for it.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Cheers
Vullnet

Answer (score 1):

Basically to need to poll the server using AJAX and check for new messages.

I suppose you have a messages table with and ID that counts up. You need to track each user's last message pointer, and send this as part of your AJAX request ad a parameter. If the server's ID is higher thsn the user's then they have a new message.

Based on the AJAX response you then alert the user.

You need to make an ASP that responds to your AJAX call, Pass it a number and it responds with "OK" (not new) or "NEW".

IT works the same way, regardless of the server-side language. Use jQuery to perform your AJAX calls.

Comment: Hi Diodeus, thanks for your response. At the moment i just have a Table that shows photo, name, and message that has been pulled from MySQL Database. I have a repeat region to show all the added news. I have a separate insert form that reloads the news page. Do you have an example that i can follow since i'm not really that smart to figure out your advice:) Thanks

Comment: It's been almost 10 years since I used classic ASP. Sorry, you'll have to dig it up on your own.